# Docker file for java project

Tags: java, spring, maven, docker, dockerfile

I have a project, which uses Mave+spring+hibernate+mysql database and I want to create a docker image of this project. I did it using these 2 commands

`$ mvn package docker:build
 $ docker push name/name`

I can create the image, but I currently have no main function so when I try to run the image It gives error no main function found. I know it should have one, but I don't know how to make that. I currently run the project by right-click->Run as->Run on server. I'm using spring tool suite. How can I create a main function that does that same thing? So when I try to run my docker image it will be ok?

CURRENT DOCKERFILE:

```
FROM java:7
ADD name-ws.jar app.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Comment: Post your docker file.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: It does build and I can run the image, but it is looking for a main function, which I don't have in my project. I run the project with spring tool suite right-click->run on server, and everything works fine locally

Comment: Is `app.jar` an executable jar file?

Comment: it gives no main manifest attribute, error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker file you are using is meant to run a spring boot application, a way of deploying spring applications that include an embedded web server in a jar.

Including the maven artifacts for spring boot might be your shortest path forward.  You'll wind up with a class that simply looks something like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RestApplication  {


  public static void main(final String... args) throws Exception {
    ApplicationContext ctx  = SpringApplication.run(RestApplication.class, args);
  }
```

If that's not what you want to do, then you can use a docker image that executes your application in tomcat, jetty, or whatever. There are plenty out there, just choose one.